# Which peers does DHT and PEX keep track of

Tags: dht

I have a question regarding DHT and PEX.  I have read a few articles that suggest that DHT updates other peers as to who is actively in a swarm a for a torrent.

1) When I have a torrent that's currently in a swarm, I check the DHT and PEX activity and shows that they are both active.  I also see, for example, something like this:  124 seeds (124 seeds currently in swarm) 459 peers (235 in swarm).

I always thought that DHT updates peers about other peers in a swarm.  Thus, Where are the other 224 peers (ie 459-235= 224) coming from? Are these peers that have paused or stopped their download? Are they simply peers that were part of the swarm recently and will eventually be taken off the DHT after a few updates?

2) Does DHT maintain torrent info hashes of users (peers), that have removed the torrent from active uploading/downloading (ie removed it from the swarm)? For example, I have clicked on a magnet link and the metadata is downloaded and my file begins to download.  After a while, I use the "remove" button on utorrent and remove the torrent which had been in the swarm and I also erase the partially downloaded file from my downloads.  But, I don't erase the data/torrent files from my Users/~/Library/Application Support/uTorrent.  Do DHT and PEX still consider you an active peer for the file? For example, when DHT refreshes/updates its table, would DHT add your ip adress/peer as still being a source for the file, even if you are not actively in the swarm?  How about PEX? would it still consider your node one that still possesses the file?

Any information on this would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

[PEX](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0011.html) is peers you are currently connected to telling you who they are connected to and also retracting the information when they disconnect. So assuming everyone implements it correctly it provides a fairly live view of the swarm. But to you use it you must be connected to some peers in the first place, so it is only a secondary peer discovery mechanism.
But that does not necessarily mean you can connect to those other peers due to firewalls or NAT or that they will connect to you.

[DHT](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html) is a global network where each node publishes itself to a list of entries associated with an infohash. Since it is independent of individual swarms it can be used as primary peer discovery mechanism. Entries are not actively deleted, they just expire with time. And DHT nodes generally do not verify the accuracy of published data. So while it is useful it may contain somewhat outdated or less reliable data.